# Class type error C++ with struct

Tags: c++, struct, set, std

I've been trying to fix this error for hours but there is something I'm missing:

I have a structure declared as:

```
typedef struct {
    bool active;
    unsigned long bbcount;
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    std::set<__uint> *bblist;
} per_thread_t;
```

Later I'm allocating memory for it and setting some variables including the `set` like this:

```
per_thread_t *data = (per_thread_t *)malloc(sizeof(per_thread_t));
data->active = false;
data->bblist = new std::set<__uint>();  
data->bblist.find(6328);
```

But I am getting the error `error C2228: left of '.find' must have class/struct/union`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: `->` for pointers. You need to dereference the pointer. So you can either go `(*data->bblist).find` or `data->bblist->find`.

Answer (score 4):

`bblist` is a pointer type. You need to access it like this:

```
data->bblist->find(6328);
```